# A schizophrenic Prince

Tags: medieval, medical

I'm working on a medieval fantasy and one of the characters is a prince who is suffering from schizophrenia. My question is how would this disease present in a medieval world?

Comment: This seems better suited to historical research than worldbuilding.  There are many articles and papers on how monarchs and leaders thought to be mentally ill were treated and considered.

Comment: Why would the disease be any different in the Middle Ages? Sure, it would go unrecognized, or identified as demonic possession or something, but the underlying disease itself would be the same.

Comment: You might check our Caligula

Comment: History has no shortage of mad emperors, kings, princes, dukes and so on. And in the Middle Ages psychiatry was much simpler than today: a person was either sane or mad. Mad people were locked up in madhouses, unless they were very rich, or kings or princes, in which case they were confined in their rooms.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine it might be interpreted as some variety of visions, possession by demons or spirits, or a curse. Schizophrenia has a lot of potential symptoms, and which ones manifest in the prince will likely determine what it is believed to be. How common such a condition is, and any prior occurrences within his family will also affect the interpretation.